# Pagination in openapi 3 REST API java code generation

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

How can I add the pagination in my swagger yaml in order to generate the correct methods in my generated interface?

So I am using this yaml:

```
 /tournaments:
get:
  summary: List of tournaments
  operationId: listTournaments
  tags:
    - tournaments
  responses:
    '200':
      description: A paged list of tournaments
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/tournaments"
    default:
      description: unexpected error
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
  parameters:
    - name: gameIds
      in: query
      description: Id of the customer
      required: false
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/gameIds'
```

and in the component section I have:

```
components:
parameters:
GameIds:
  in: query
  schema:
    type: array
    items:
      type: integer
      format: int64
  name: the GameIds
  description: >
    The Game Ids.
```

Do I have to add a configOption in my gradle build in order to generate a @ParameterObject on the Pageable object on your controller method?

```
configOptions = [
        configPackage       : "com.tournaments.api.engine.config",
        java8               : "true",
        dateLibrary         : "java17",
        serializationLibrary: "jackson",
        library             : "spring-boot",
        useBeanValidation   : "true",
        interfaceOnly       : "true",
        serializableModel   : "true",
        useTags             : "true",
        additionalModelTypeAnnotations: "@lombok.Builder;@lombok.NoArgsConstructor;@lombok.AllArgsConstructor"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Openapi generator you should achieve that by adding the following extendion in your Openapi definition :

```
paths:
  /your_url:
    get:
      x-spring-paginated: true
      responses:
      ...
```

Using Maven you need `springdoc-openapi-data-rest` dependency but I don't know how to do the same with Gradle.
The generated `pageable` will be annotated with `@ParameterObject`.